# jQuery slideshow with full width like tumblr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, tumblr

**Look at this slideshow (wait a few seconds):**

http://www.tumblr.com

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin that does the same thing.

**My requirements**

- It should be as fast as tumblr slideshow.
- It should adapt to my / your screen width like tumblr. (very important)
- Tumblr slideshow runs automatically. I want prev / next buttons (anchor tags) instead.
- Lightweight is always a nice.

**I found one that was almost what I want:**

http://www.visibilityinherit.com/code/horizontal-website-demo2.php

It feels slow and there are no settings to change that. It has no prev / next buttons.

Comment: I really like **[jQuery Cycle](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)** - flexible, responsive, and customizable.

Comment: By the way, that horizontal-scroll plugin you link to is pretty easy to make faster; take a look at where it decides the duration based on the jQuery version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. FlexSlider has all what I'm asking for.
http://flex.madebymufffin.com/